# VBA to find a value with 2 criteria and seperate to show the smallest and largest value (Date)

Tags: excel, vba, criteria

I am new for VBA and I am trying to find the smallest and largest date which fulfill 2 criterias.

If I find a date by using non-vba method, I can use `={index(lookup value)match(true,(criteria1*criteria2),0))}` to find out the date.

But, above function cannot find the smallest date and largest date, it can only show the first result in the table.

[image]

[image]

As you see, I want to find out Column D (early date) and Column E (deadline date) by criterias

1. "Area"

and

2. "Floor_Level"

I have no idea how to write the VBA code...

I only know I shall use function like this:

```
Function findvalue(ByVal info1 As String, ByVal info2 As String) As Variant
```

Sorry for the long question. I am learning the vba recently and a little bit difficult to find the solution like this case......

Comment: Maybe look at MAXIFS/MINIFS

Comment: You could also do this using Power Query -- use the Group By function and select Max and Min for aggregation.

Comment: I am now using {min(if(........))}  and {max(if...)}  to temporarily solve user's request...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object). I make this code with dummy data and with a simple output. If the key (area+floor) has one date, the date repeats as min and max. If no, the left date is min, the right is max

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MinMaxDates()
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, D As Variant, rng As Range, cl As Range, key As Variant, a, b, cnt As Long
    
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1), Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1))
    For Each cl In rng
        key = cl.Text & "+" & cl.Offset(, 1).Text
        D = cl.Offset(, 2).Value
        If dict.Exists(key) Then
            a = dict(key)
            If a(0) > D Then a(0) = D
            If a(1) < D Then a(1) = D
            dict(key) = a
        Else
            dict.Add key, Array(D, D)
        End If
    Next
    
    ' output
    Range("E1").Resize(, 4) = Array("Area", "Floor", "MinDate", "MaxDate")
    cnt = 1
    For Each key In dict.Keys
       a = Split(key, "+")
       b = dict(key)
       If b(0) = b(1) Then b(1) = "No max date"
       Range("E1").Offset(cnt).Resize(, 4) = Array(a(0), a(1), b(0), b(1))
       cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That 's great,  i will try it in office later,  thanks